# Current contaminant levels from Deep Water Horizon oil spill?

Tags: ocean

The [Deep Water Horizon oil spill](https://www.britannica.com/event/Deepwater-Horizon-oil-spill-of-2010) occurred in 2010 and is known as the largest marine oil spill ever. I heard on the radio the other day, from a not so reliable source, that contaminant levels have dropped in the 90% range since then due to naturally occurring organisms that feed off the hydrocarbons.  Is there any good current research out there now that shows what current concentrations are compared to what they were after the spill?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Concerning

> Is there any good current research out there

the most recent study I found is

- **[Persistence and biodegradation of oil at the ocean floor following Deepwater Horizon](http://www.pnas.org/content/114/1/E9.full)**

> In this work, we assess the extent of degradation over 4 y postspill
> for each of 125 petroleum hydrocarbons that contaminated the seafloor.

and compares levels from thousands of sample sites. This seems to qualify 'good current research'.

Comment: They also added surfactants at the source to breakup the flow into high surface area droplets more available to microorganism attack.

Comment: Yeah, I should have been more specific with what I was looking for when I wrote "good current research".  This was the most recent research I could find too and it is very informative.  Answer accepted.